# Is there Go function comparable to boost::uniform_int?

Tags: c++, go, random, distribution

I'm translating a tool from C++ to Go. The C++ tool uses the boost::random library and invokes boost::uniform_int. I'd like to know if there's a comparable 'out of the box' function in Go. If not I need some help building my own.

I've combed through Go's math/rand package but didn't find anything that was obviously equivalent.

Here's [a link](https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/doc/html/boost/uniform_int.html) to boost's documentation

This is function declaration/invocation in the C++ tool

```
boost::uniform_int<unsigned int> randomDistOp(1, 100);
```

Comment: Tak a look at rand.Source (https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Source), it promises "uniformly-distributed pseudo-random int64 values in the range [0, 1<<63).".

Comment: As for limiting it to 100 without losing uniformity, here is a nice read: https://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/27/a-fast-alternative-to-the-modulo-reduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Intn` method should give you what you want.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    fmt.Println(1 + r.Intn(100))
}
```

This provides uniformly random integers from [0, n). To set a different lower bound, just add it to the result. Just to be clear, `Intn(100)` will return numbers up to but excluding 100, so adding 1 will give you the proper range from 1 to 100.